# Controlling led using arduino

Tags: arduino, led, led-strip, led-driver

I want to control 25 red led (not rgb) using arduino uno. Basically i want to make a led chaser. Can anyone help me regarding this project?

Comment: Please specify more details about this project.Are they RGB LEDs? Are they addressable LEDs? How do you want to control them?

Comment: You need to show what you have tried, and what you are struggling with. Don't expect users to draw circuit diagrams and write code for you for free

Comment: @Makoto Thanks for your reply.  I want to know the process not the whole circuit diagram.

Comment: You need to be more specific. What exactly are you unsure about? Start by writing down an approach that you think would work

Comment: If you are using WS2812 or similar LEDs (adressable) you should take a look at adafruits neopixel library for arduino.

Comment: A couple of  PCF8575 16 bit I2C chips (or breakout boards) should do the trick giving you 32 I/O lines from a simple I2C interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I strongly recommend you to read about serial data and shift registers.You can use a few pins on any micro controller to handle large I/O operations using a shift register.If you're using only 25 LEDs,the digital read function would be sufficient,but if you try to scale the project,it may be too slow,so you can also read about hacking the ardunio to read the digital pins in a much faster way.